# Tips on algorithm or steps to find word sequences given a string

Tags: python

been going through this the whole day, cant figure out what to do here, i feel that I need to use recursive function here, any tips will be great (steps to take, algorithm, etc)

Given a word w, a good subsequence of w is defined as a word w' such that

- all letters in w' are different;
- w' is obtained from w by deleting some letters in w.

Returns the list of all good subsequences, without duplicates, in lexicographic order

Expected results:

```
def good_subsequences(word):
'''
>>> good_subsequences('')
['']
>>> good_subsequences('aaa')
['', 'a']
>>> good_subsequences('aaabbb')
['', 'a', 'ab', 'b']
>>> good_subsequences('aaabbc')
['', 'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'ac', 'b', 'bc', 'c']
>>> good_subsequences('aaabbaaa')
['', 'a', 'ab', 'b', 'ba']
>>> good_subsequences('abbbcaaabccc')
['', 'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'ac', 'acb', 'b', 'ba', 'bac', 'bc', 'bca', 'c', 'ca', 'cab', 'cb']
>>> good_subsequences('abbbcaaabcccaaa')
['', 'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'ac', 'acb', 'b', 'ba', 'bac','bc', 'bca', 'c', 'ca', 'cab', 'cb', 'cba']
>>> good_subsequences('abbbcaaabcccaaabbbbbccab')
['', 'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'ac', 'acb', 'b', 'ba', 'bac','bc', 'bca', 'c', 'ca', 'cab', 'cb', 'cba']
'''
```

What I am thinking is

```
def good_subsequences(word):
L = ['']
current_char = ''
for i in range(0,len(word)):
    if  current_char != word[i]:
        L.append(word[i])
        current_char = word[i]
L = ''.join(L)
#call up _good_sub(L)

def _good_sub(word):
    #do a recursive function
```

Comment: This seems very similar to finding the powerset of a list (here it would the characters of your word string). I would run the algorithm for getting the powerset and then trim each set in the powerset by removing the duplicates (using a set or such). I would also remove the original list from the power set since no items would have been removed technically. The powerset algorithm is fairly documented and would be a good start here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive generator approach with subsequent sorting and very little overproduction in comparison to some of the brute-force solutions:

```
from itertools import groupby

def simple(word, without=''):
    # remove adjacent duplicates and anything in 'without'
    return ''.join(k for k, _ in groupby(word) if k not in without)

def _gs(word):
    seen = set()
    s_word = simple(word)
    yield ''
    for i, char in enumerate(s_word):
        for sub in _gs(simple(s_word[i+1:], char)):
            new_sub = char + sub
            if new_sub not in seen:
                seen.add(new_sub)
                yield new_sub

def good_subsequences(word):
    return sorted(_gs(word))

>>> good_subsequences('')
['']
>>> good_subsequences('aaa')
['', 'a']
>>> good_subsequences('aaabbb')
['', 'a', 'ab', 'b']
>>> good_subsequences('aaabbc')
['', 'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'ac', 'b', 'bc', 'c']
>>> good_subsequences('aaabbaaa')
['', 'a', 'ab', 'b', 'ba']
>>> good_subsequences('abbbcaaabccc')
['', 'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'ac', 'acb', 'b', 'ba', 'bac', 'bc', 'bca', 'c', 'ca', 'cab', 'cb']
```

Comment: It took me a while understanding groupby, but this is gold, thanks! I especially like that simple function, I will definitely use it often. but can you explain a bit for me how this work ('for sub in _gs(simple(s_word[i+1:], char)):')

Comment: That loop iterates through all the good subsequences of the remainder of the word without any occurrences of char removed.

Comment: The initial subsequence is always the empty string. `sub` should never be `None`, however.

Comment: sub is empty string because of yield '' isit?

Comment: Exactly,`''` is the first good subsequence of any given string according to your examples.

Comment: I sort of get it and sort of don't how to use the yield function, any chance I can use return instead somehow? hahaha...

Comment: @DSt_FTW Sure, create an empty list at the top of the function. Whenever something is yielded, append that something to the list instead. Return that list at the bottom of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could start to do something like:

```
def good_subsequences(word):
    Letter_order = [word[0]]
    substrings = ['']
    for i in range(1,len(word)):
        if  Letter_order[-1] != word[i]:
            Letter_order .append(word[i])
```

Now after the for loop you have array that has all the letter orders that need to be included in you final substrings array. Here you could probably use a helper function to go over all the possible combinations of letters in order based on their sequence in the Letter_order array.

Answer (score 0):

this is just brute force. do not try this when you have many different characters in your alphabet... but it may perform ok if you have many repetitions of your characters.

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations

def in_word(strg, word):
    i = 0
    for char in strg:
        try:
            i = word.index(char, i)
        except ValueError:
            return False
    return True

def good_subsequences(word):
    ret = ['']
    alphabet = set(word)
    for r in range(len(alphabet)):
        for comb in combinations(alphabet, r+1):
            for perm in permutations(comb, r+1):
                strg = ''.join(perm)
                if in_word(strg, word):
                    ret.append(strg)
    return ret
```

it reduces your input to the unique letters using `set` then loops over the 1, 2, 3, ..., n-letter combinations and then loops over the permutations of these. `in_word` then checks if that permutation appears in your original word (in that order).

Answer (score 0):

**THIS ONLY EXTRACTS CONTIGUOUS SUBSEQUENCE**

I believe this is a simple greedy search:

```
def good_subsequences(w):
    L = {''}
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(w)):
        for k in range(i, j):
            L.add(w[i:j])
        while j < len(w) and w[j] not in w[i:j]:
            j += 1
            L.add(w[i:j])
    return L
```

While in your example, there's one thing I don't understand. Why would `'abbbcaaabccc'` generate `'bac'`?

Comment: Because subsequences do not have to be contiguous.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Oh that totally make sense, forget about this answer

Comment: Well, it is not immediately obvious from the word "subsequece", so the question is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not a „full“ answer and doesn’t provide code for you, but this is an algorithmical approach for your question.

Start by rephrasing the question in a way that it is equivalent to the original question. But „closer“ to a possible implementation.

Given a word w, find

- longest good subsequences (longest subsequences of different letters)
- all subsequences of a good one are good (but subsequences of different long ones may overlap: *abc* and *acb* both have *ab* as subsequence)

It is easy to cope with second part (just build subsequences and eliminate duplicates)

To get the longest ones, you need to keep each letter once, retaining different positions.

But first, note that repeating letters do not matter. 
*aaabbbbbbbccaaa* will have same output as *abca*. So **first**, clear all consecutive dublicates

Now, you need to combine all positions of each letter with each other. E.g. if letter *a* appears 3 times in your word, you need to try 3 times. If letter b appiars twice, you need to try two times, and so on. Example:

Abacba has at most 3x2x1 = 6 of them, each containing one a, one b and one c => abc, acb, bac, acb, bca, cba.

Now drop duplicate longest good sequences and go ahead to the second bullet point above